# Built-in functions in c++

Tags: c++, function, built-in

I was browsing through some codes at the end of the contest and found out that many people were using functions like `__gcd(int,int)` . What are these functions ? Similar functions include

`__builtin_popcount(int)`

`__builtin_ctz(int)`

`__builtin_clz(int)`

Where can I study about these functions ? Googling it didn't help much.

Comment: Those are GCC intrinsics. They don't exist in the C++ standard.

Comment: Google was quite helpful for me: [click me](https://www.google.com/search?q=builtin_clz&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=les%3Bcdymh&gs_nf=3&gs_mss=_builtin_clz&tok=GIrhzLM76KFGCG5_DZOr2Q&pq=__builtin_clz&cp=12&gs_id=137&xhr=t&q=__builtin_popcount&pf=p&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=o8V&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=__builtin_po&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=97301e76c1e40a6c&bpcl=38625945&biw=1280&bih=895) -- What search term did you use?

Comment: All global names starting with a single underscore are reserved by the standard, and two underscores are typically used for compiler extensions.

Comment: “the contest” – *what* contest?

Comment: The __builtin_* are from gcc, as noted before. `std::__gcd` is from [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a01576.html#a64690c88f80577f3052168f0322749e6)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Codechef -November Cook-Off 2012 contest

Answer (score 4):

Those are all GCC specifics. you can read about them here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions - but be aware, they're NOT C/C++ Standards.