# Inbuilt __gcd(A,B) function in C++

Tags: c++

recently I get to know about a special function in c++ :  `__gcd(A,B)`. this will return the greatest common divisor of A and B.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

main()
{
cout<<__gcd(10,40); //op: 10
}
```

is there any special reason for starting function definition with 2 underscores?

It could be as simple as `gcd(A,B)` like other STL functions.

Comment: *like other built-in functions* which ones are you referring to?

Comment: I don't believe it was intended for the public to use.

Comment: @Borgleader like sort() ,qsort()  ,swap( ) etc

Comment: @JerryGoyal all those are standard library functions (as in, they are required to be there by the C++ standard), __gcd is gcc specific and therefore not portable. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443463/built-in-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation, which means that you are not allowed to define such names in your code, and there are no standard guarantees what those names mean if they do exist. However, a vendor might choose to document some such names, in which case you can use them with the product for which the vendor documents them.

Answer (score 6):

In C++17 there are standard library functions for GCD and LCM.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main ()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << std::gcd(a,b) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```